# calling webapi from angularjs service - Unable to get property 'post' of undefined or null reference

Tags: angularjs

I have the following function in my service:

```
myapp.service('addParentService', function ($http) {
    vm.returnParent = function ($http) {
        for (i in vm.parent) {
            //alert('getValues : ' + vm.parent[i].name);
        }


        var data = { name: 'Jeff', email: 'jv@test.com', phone: '5551212', carrierName: 'ATT' };
        $http.post(
            'http://localhost:10000/api/people/PostRegister/',
            JSON.stringify(data),
            {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            }
        ).success(function (data) {
            alert(result);
        });

});
```

I ran into the issue where I wasn't injecting $http.  Now when I run this function I get the following error:

> Unable to get property 'post' of undefined or null reference

This my controller:

```
myapp.controller('AddParentController', function ($scope,$http, addParentService) {
    $scope.addParentService = addParentService;
});
```

Comment: Are you injecting `$http` into your service / controller?

Comment: @DavidBarker - I updated my question with my controller code.  Am I doing it correctly?

Comment: No, there is no reason to injectct `$http` to controller (or you are not showing the full content)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inject `$http` in your service, if you haven't already. No need to inject it on your controller if you're not invoking it from there (which I guess you're not doing, because if you are, what's the point in making a new service...?)

However, you're including `$http` (which is a service) as a parameter of your `returnParent` function; that's why the `undefined or null reference` error pops up.

So, your first line of code should be `vm.returnParent = function () {`

Good luck!

Comment: Once I changed it from the returnParent function to the service itself I was able to see that it was calling the WebAPI controller method.  I believe this is the answer to my issue.

Answer (score 0):

$http is a service. Include angular-resource.js also in your project/file. Then the error will not be there.
Also you need to inject ngResource to your module.
Refer this link for specific details:
https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_11

Abhilash D K

MCP

Comment: `$http` is independent to `ngResource` - you can use `$http` service out of the box without adding additional files.

Comment: Oh Okay. I did not know that. Sorry for that info. I just followed the link I posted and thought ngResource is needed.